# 3rd Week of Programming, just looking for tips

Tags: java, performance

I'm am in my 3rd week of Java in school, and I just submitted a payroll-calculating application. Being an extreme newbie, I know that my code is likely horrific and would give a seasoned programmer a migraine - but that's why I'm here. This assignment has already been turned-in, so I'm not looking for anyone to do my work for me, I'm just wondering about a few specific things in my code, as well as maybe some general "You should have done it this way" feedback, if anyone is so inclined to help a guy with 3 weeks experience get better.

First off, here is my code:

```
// Payroll.java
// This program calculates an employee's net pay
// minus Federal tax (11% off the gross) with Overtime
// Daniel Zaleski
// 08/17/2014

/** Import Scanner */

import java.util.Scanner; // Scanner to read user input

/** Create Class */

public class Payroll // Class declaration
{

    public static double hoursWorked; // Declare hoursWorked as a double

    public double hoursWorked()
    {
        return hoursWorked;
    }

    public static double hourlyRate; // Declare hourlyRate as a double

    public double hourlyRate()
    {
        return hourlyRate;
    }

    private double taxedPay; // Declare taxedPay as a double

    public double taxedPay()
    {
        return taxedPay;
    }

    private double netPay; // Declare netPay as a double

    public double netPay()
    {
        return netPay;
    }

    private static double grossPay; // Defining variable grossPay
    private static double overtimePay; // Defining variable overtimePay
    private static double overtimeHours; // Defining variable overtimeHours

    public static void main(String[] args) // Main method
    {

        int i = 8; // Setting the application loop
        while(i < 9) // Setting the termination variable which doesn't exist to continue loop
        {

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // Creating the scanner

            /** Prompt for first name */
            String firstName; // Variable for the first name
            System.out.println("\nEnter Your First Name: (Enter the name quit (all lowercase) to terminate application)\n");
            firstName = input.next();

            // Setting the loop termination variable "quit"
            if(firstName.equals("quit"))
            {
                System.out.println("You have terminated the Application. Have a nice day.\n");
                break;
            }

            /** Prompt for last name */
            String lastName; // Variable for the last name
            System.out.println("\nEnter Your Last Name:\n ");
            lastName = input.next();

            String completeName; // Setting the full name
            completeName = firstName + " " + lastName;
            System.out.println("\nHello " + completeName);

            /** Prompt for hours worked */
            double hoursWorked; // Asking for hours worked
            System.out.println("\nPlease Enter Your Hours Worked\n ");
            hoursWorked = input.nextDouble();
            if(hoursWorked < 0.1)
            {
                System.out.print("Please Enter a Positive Value\n ");
                System.out.println("\nPlease Enter Your Hours Worked (Greater Than 0)\n ");
                hoursWorked = input.nextDouble();
            }

            /** Prompt for hourly rate */
            double hourlyRate; // Defining hourlyRate
            System.out.println("\nPlease Enter Your Hourly Rate\n ");
            hourlyRate = input.nextDouble();
            if(hourlyRate < 0.1)
            {
                System.out.print("Please Enter a Positive Value\n ");
                System.out.println("\nPlease Enter Your Hourly Rate (Greater Than 0)\n ");
                hourlyRate = input.nextDouble();
            }

            /** Figure Out Overtime Pay */
            if(hoursWorked > 40.1)
            {
                overtimePay = 1.5 * hourlyRate * (hoursWorked - 40.0); // Figuring overtimePay
            }

            if(hoursWorked > 40.1)
            {
                grossPay = hourlyRate * hoursWorked + overtimePay; // Figuring overtime gross
            }

            else
            {
                grossPay = hourlyRate * hoursWorked; // Non overtime gross
            }


            /** Figure Out Overtime Hours */

            if(hoursWorked > 40.1)
            {
                overtimeHours = hoursWorked - 40; // Figuring overtimeHours
            }

            double federalTax; // Defining the Federal Tax variable
            federalTax = .11;

            double taxedPay; // Defining the taxedPay variable
            taxedPay = federalTax * grossPay;

            double netPay; // Defining the netPay variable
            netPay = grossPay - taxedPay;

            /** System print declarations */
            System.out.println("\nHello " + completeName); // Print user name
            System.out.println("\nYour Hours Worked this Cycle Are: " + hoursWorked); // Print hours worked
            System.out.printf("\nYour Current Hourly Rate is: $%,.2f\n", hourlyRate); // Print and format hourlyRate

            if(hoursWorked > 40.0)
            {
                System.out.printf("\nYour Overtime Hours This Cycle: %.2f\n", overtimeHours); // Print and format hourlyRate
                System.out.printf("\nYour Overtime Pay This Cycle: $%,.2f\n", overtimePay); // Print and format hourlyRate
            }

            System.out.printf("\nYour Gross Pay this Cycle is: $%,.2f\n", grossPay); // Print and format grossPay
            System.out.printf("\nThe Federal Tax you Paid this Cycle is: $%,.2f\n", taxedPay); // Print and format taxedPay
            System.out.println("\nYour Federal Tax Rate is Currently: (11%)"); // Print Federal tax rate
            System.out.printf("\nYour Net Pay for the Cycle is: $%,.2f\n", netPay); // Print and format netPay
            System.out.println("\nThe word quit was not detected. Let's do it again!\n"); // Create space to do the loop again

        } // End loop while
    } // End main method
} // End Payroll class
```

So my specific questions are as follows:

1. How would I program a loop where the system prompts for a re-entry of hoursWorked and hourlyRate if the value is `<= 0`? I know I have it re promoting once, but after that, the program just moves on in both cases. I can't figure out how to program that loop.
2. The app is supposed to loop infinitely, until the word "quit" is entered. It does, but I know the way I did it is a little wonky, in using a variable that will never be proven, because I never try to prove it. Is that accepted practice, or is there a better way to do that?
3. Am I declaring the user-input variables correctly? It works...but I can't find many other people who are doing it the way I'm doing it.

   That's it. I know everyone is busy, but if any experienced Java programmers have time to help a fledgling, I would really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you should post it at [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: The first and most important thing I'd like to tell you is that you should either use the auto-formatting feature in Eclipse (if you are using that) using Ctrl+Shift+F, or just be consistent with your indentations so it won't look like a mess. Indentation is very important, otherwise your code will be a jarbled mess and that is not good at all, especially if you need to debug things.

Comment: Why do you have the Payroll class with variables that you never use?
You could essentially run this wihtout this class as just a main method and it would do the same thing. You don't even initialize the object Oo

Comment: The methods that return your properties like hoursWorked() are so called getter. There is a common convention how to name these methods. If you have a property called "name" the getter-method would be named "getName()". In many cases you will also have a setter which would be namend "setName(String name)". The convention comes from the JavaBeans Guidelines You can read more about this convention  here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/

Comment: Conform yourself to the Java code conventions

Comment: @stealthjong the brace placement to *Allman Style* is my fault, sorry about that (i just put it in the autoformatter and that's how i have it set because I prefer it despite the conventions) - it was still a better alternative than the original version :p

Comment: Instead of the while-loop while(i < 9) you'd better use a for-loop. For-loops define a counter variable i and a break condition that depends on the counter i. while loops usually don't have a counter like i.

Comment: if(hoursWorked < 0.1) is also true if hoursWorked has positive values like 0.01. Correct would be < 0

Comment: break your main method's code into different logical methods. A big method is nightmare for anyone to debug/understand , having logical separation helps to know the context even when one doesn't know much about requirements.

Comment: Sikorsky, I thought about that, but due to limited experience, was scared to add additional methods. I will, however, rewrite this breaking the code into smaller methods to practice now that the deadline is passed and I have some time. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed some stuff and added some stuff, it's not perfect but it should help a bit.

```
public class Payroll
{
    public double hoursWorked; // should not be static

    public double hoursWorked() //should be getHoursWorked() and should have setter
    {
        return hoursWorked;
    }

    public Payroll setHoursWorked(double hoursWorked)
    {
        this.hoursWorked = hoursWorked;
        return this; //returning itself instead of 'void' allows method chaining
    }

    public double hourlyRate; // should not be static

    public double hourlyRate() //should be getHourlyRate() and should have setter
    {
        return hourlyRate;
    }

    private double taxedPay; // Declare taxedPay as a double

    public double taxedPay() //should be getTaxedPay() and should have setter
    {
        return taxedPay;
    }

    private double netPay; 

    public double netPay() //should be getNetPay() and should have setter
    {
        return netPay;
    }

    private double grossPay; // should not be static, should have getter/setter
    private double overtimePay; // should not be static, should have getter/setter
    private double overtimeHours; // should not be static, should have getter/setter

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int i = 8; //you are basically using this variable only as a substitute for "while(true)".
        Scanner input = null;
        try
        {
            input = new Scanner(System.in); // should not re-allocate the Scanner each call, it is a resource that is ought to be closed
            do // should just use a do-while loop
            {    
                String firstName;
                System.out.println("\nEnter Your First Name: (Enter the name quit (all lowercase)     to terminate application)\n");
                firstName = input.next();

                if("quit".equals(firstName)) //this way, the app doesn't crash with NullPointerException if firstName is null
                {
                    System.out.println("You have terminated the Application. Have a nice day.\n");
                    break;
                }

                String lastName;
                System.out.println("\nEnter Your Last Name:\n ");
                lastName = input.next();

                String completeName;
                completeName = firstName + " " + lastName;
                System.out.println("\nHello " + completeName);

                PayRoll payRoll = new PayRoll(); //have an actual class for the data instead of using it statically
                //...
                payRoll.setHoursWorked(input.nextDouble()); //use setters like that, also there is no exception handling in case it's not a double from the input
                if(payRoll.getHoursWorked() < 0.1)
                {
                    //...
                }

                // ...
                // print print print print etc
            } 
            while(i < 9); //to be honest, this is not very descriptive, a boolean variable would say more about what is happening here and up to what point it is supposed to run and when this loop should end
        }
        finally
        {
            if(input != null)
            {
                input.close(); // Scanner is a resource that is meant to be closed after usage
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also remove creation of Scanner out of the loop. and use a variable to check if "quit" has been entered i.e, `while(!quitEntered)` .

Comment: The only strange thing to me is that the Payroll itself doesn't seem to store the names in any way. I think that should be part of the class. To be honest, I'd put the `main()` function into a seperate class called `Main` and I would have the `Payroll` independently only to store data. @TheLostMind I did not notice that for some reason and I'll modify that part a bit.

Comment: Okay, I've added some extra comments, removed the original comments so that the comments are readily visible, and also closing the Scanner

Comment: `i` is not initialized

Comment: I thought it was set somewhere in the middle of the code, but it's not, so I initialized it now, thanks for pointing it out. Also, thanks for the accept, although Michał Schielmann's answer goes more into detail on how to decompose the application logic into methods, I didn't really end up doing that myself.

Answer (score 1):

To run the `while` loop until word `quit` you can use

```
while(true)
{
    //your code
   if(firstName.equals("quit"))
    {
        System.out.println("You have terminated the Application. Have a nice day.\n");
        break;
    }
}
```

in you `/** Figure Out Overtime Pay */` and  `/** Figure Out Overtime Hours */` You could have write less code. see this:

```
 /** Figure Out Overtime Hours and Pay */
  if(hoursWorked > 40.1)
    {
        overtimeHours = hoursWorked - 40; // Figuring overtimeHours
        overtimePay = 1.5 * hourlyRate *overtimeHours ; // Figuring overtimePay
        grossPay = hourlyRate * hoursWorked + overtimePay; // Figuring overtime gross

    }
    else
    {
        overtimeHours=0;
        overtimePay=0;
        grossPay = hourlyRate * hoursWorked; // Non overtime gross
    }
```

Another thing is if you write getter/setter for any class variable try to follow this convention

your code :

```
public static double hoursWorked; // Declare hoursWorked as a double
public double hoursWorked() // this is the getter mothod of hoursWorked
{
    return hoursWorked;
}
```

The method name should be like

```
public double getHoursWorked() // this is the getter mothod of hoursWorked
{
    return hoursWorked;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Saif, I will practice writing the loop this way.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use a while loop with an condition (while hoursWorked > 0)
2. Again, you can use a while() loop with a break statement in case of 'quit' input. - i.e.

   while(true) {doCalculations; if firstName.equals("quit") break;}
3. As for variables - it's a good practice to declare all your fields private in a class. Static should not be an default option, and should be used for special needs.

As Java is Object Oriented Language try to take advantage of it. Use a Payroll class and create instance methods for each opeartion - like getFirstName(), getLastName(), calculateTax(), printDeclarations(). That way the code will be simpler, easier to maintain and more readable. Next step would be to create separate classes instead of methods - like TaxCalculator, DeclarationPrinter and so on.

Moreover try to avoid 'magic numbers' - it's not a good habit to have them in your code. U are using 40 in separate places. What if this number was changed by the government - you'll have to find all 40's in your code. Try to declare it as a constant(final instance field).

Try not to mix field declarations with methods declarations. Its more readable to keep them separate, but with the same order. It's good that you stick to one formatting pattern througout all your code.

Try the code below and see if it more readable for you:

```
// Payroll.java
// This program calculates an employee's net pay
// minus Federal tax (11% off the gross) with Overtime
// Daniel Zaleski
// 08/17/2014

/** Import Scanner */

import java.util.Scanner; // Scanner to read user input

/** Create Class */

public class Payroll // Class declaration
{
    private static final Double NORMAL_WORKING_HOURS = 40d;
    private static final Double SOME_FACTOR = 1.5;
    private static final Double FEDERAL_TAX = 0.11;

    private Scanner input;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String completeName;

    private double hoursWorked; // Declare hoursWorked as a double
    private double hourlyRate; // Declare hourlyRate as a double
    private double taxedPay; // Declare taxedPay as a double
    private double grossPay; // Defining variable grossPay
    private double netPay; // Declare netPay as a double
    private double overtimePay; // Defining variable overtimePay
    private double overtimeHours; // Defining variable overtimeHours

    public Payroll(Scanner input)
    {
        this.input = input;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            inputFirstName();
            if (firstName.equals("quit"))
            {
                break;
            }
            inputLastName();
            createUser();
            welcomeUser();

            inputHoursWorked();
            inputHourlyRate();
            calculateOvertimeHours();
            calculateOvertimePay();
            calculateGrossPay();
            calculateTaxPay();
            calculateNetPay();
            printDeclaration();
        }

        System.out.println("You have terminated the Application. Have a nice day.\n");
    }

    private void inputFirstName()
    {
        /** Prompt for first name */
        System.out.println("\nEnter Your First Name: (Enter the name quit (all lowercase) to terminate application)\n");
        firstName = input.next();
    }

    private void inputLastName()
    {
        /** Prompt for first name */
        System.out.println("\nEnter Your Last Name\n");
        lastName = input.next();
    }

    private void createUser()
    {
        completeName = firstName + " " + lastName;
    }

    private void welcomeUser()
    {

        System.out.println("\nHello " + completeName);
    }

    private void inputHoursWorked()
    {
        System.out.println("\nPlease Enter Your Hours Worked\n ");
        hoursWorked = input.nextDouble();

        while(hoursWorked <= 0)
        {
            System.out.print("Please Enter a Positive Value\n ");
            hoursWorked = input.nextDouble();
        }
    }

    private void inputHourlyRate()
    {
        System.out.println("\nPlease Enter Your Hourly Rate\n ");
        hourlyRate = input.nextDouble();

        while(hoursWorked <= 0)
        {
            System.out.println("\nPlease Enter Your Hourly Rate (Greater Than 0)\n ");
            hourlyRate = input.nextDouble();
        }
    }


    private void calculateOvertimeHours()
    {
        if(hoursWorked > NORMAL_WORKING_HOURS)
        {
            overtimeHours = hoursWorked - NORMAL_WORKING_HOURS; // Figuring overtimeHours
        }
    }

    private void calculateOvertimePay()
    {
        overtimePay = SOME_FACTOR * hourlyRate * (overtimeHours); // Figuring overtimePay
    }

    private void calculateTaxPay()
    {
        taxedPay = FEDERAL_TAX * grossPay;
    }

    private void calculateGrossPay()
    {
        /** Figure Out Overtime Pay */
        if(overtimeHours > 0)
        {
            grossPay = hourlyRate * hoursWorked + overtimePay; // Figuring overtime gross
        }
        else
        {
            grossPay = hourlyRate * hoursWorked; // Non overtime gross
        }
    }

    private void calculateNetPay()
    {
        netPay = grossPay - taxedPay;
    }

    private void printDeclaration()
    {
        /** System print declarations */
        System.out.println("\nHello " + completeName); // Print user name
        System.out.println("\nYour Hours Worked this Cycle Are: " + hoursWorked); // Print hours worked
        System.out.printf("\nYour Current Hourly Rate is: $%,.2f\n", hourlyRate); // Print and format hourlyRate

        if(overtimeHours > 0)
        {
            System.out.printf("\nYour Overtime Hours This Cycle: %.2f\n", overtimeHours); // Print and format hourlyRate
            System.out.printf("\nYour Overtime Pay This Cycle: $%,.2f\n", overtimePay); // Print and format hourlyRate
        }

        System.out.printf("\nYour Gross Pay this Cycle is: $%,.2f\n", grossPay); // Print and format grossPay
        System.out.printf("\nThe Federal Tax you Paid this Cycle is: $%,.2f\n", taxedPay); // Print and format taxedPay
        System.out.println("\nYour Federal Tax Rate is Currently: (11%)"); // Print Federal tax rate
        System.out.printf("\nYour Net Pay for the Cycle is: $%,.2f\n", netPay); // Print and format netPay
        System.out.println("\nThe word quit was not detected. Let's do it again!\n"); // Create space to do the loop again
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) // Main method
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        new Payroll(input).run();
    } // End main method
} // End Payroll class
```

The output is as follows:

Enter Your First Name: (Enter the name quit (all lowercase) to terminate application)

Michał

Enter Your Last Name

Schielmann

Hello Michał Schielmann

Please Enter Your Hours Worked

42

Please Enter Your Hourly Rate

250

Hello Michał Schielmann

Your Hours Worked this Cycle Are: 42.0

Your Current Hourly Rate is: $250,00

Your Overtime Hours This Cycle: 2,00

Your Overtime Pay This Cycle: $750,00

Your Gross Pay this Cycle is: $11 250,00

The Federal Tax you Paid this Cycle is: $1 237,50

Your Federal Tax Rate is Currently: (11%)

Your Net Pay for the Cycle is: $10 012,50

The word quit was not detected. Let's do it again!

Enter Your First Name: (Enter the name quit (all lowercase) to terminate application)

quit
You have terminated the Application. Have a nice day.

Comment: Mike, thank you. This really helps me. I'm going to try and re-write my program a few times for practice, and your feedback will really help.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.
I think it's important that you try to fragment your code to methods/classes as soon as possible and take advantage of object oriented programming. If you develop bad habits, and develop thinking in procedural mode instad of OO mode, then later it may be difficult to switch.

Comment: I come from an HTML / CSS background, so it definitely is a shift in mentality for me.

Answer (score 0):

In your person class , dont use static variable.

Static means across all instance are same value. In case if you are adding two person , then both the reference are same value. latest one override everything.

Your quit approach is ok. Its normally way to quitting your scenario.

For Iteration based Please prefer below

```
            while (true) {
                if (hoursWorked < 0.1) {
                    System.out.print("Please Enter a Positive Value\n ");
                    System.out
                            .println("\nPlease Enter Your Hours Worked (Greater Than 0)\n ");
                    hoursWorked = input.nextDouble();
                } else 
                    break;
            }
```

Comment: Siva, thank you for the example on how to do this better.

Answer (score 0):

Okay let us start at the beginning. You are using methods to get the values of your variables. A convention which is used for this is to call the method "get" + variableName.
Something like this:

```
public double getHoursWorked() {
    return this.hoursWorked;
}
```

If you want to set this variable you can use the same convention. You call the function "set" + variableName.
In your main function you should try to use additional functions for you behavior. First of you could create a function calculatePayroll and in this function you will call additional functions which will calculate the desired things. The sections to turn into a functions are already defined by you in the commnents. For "/** Figure Out Overtime Hours */" you could create a function:

```
public double calculateOvertimeHours() {
    //do your calculation here
}
```

This will split your code into some functions which are easier to test and to debug if you program does not work properly.

Comment: I had a feeling I was calling the variables in a way that wasn't conventional. Thank you Deuteo for the great feedback!

Comment: No problem. I forgot to mention that you should declare your variables as private and the getter / setter functions as public.